# Retrofit and OkHttp basic authentication

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am trying to add basic authentication (username and password) to a Retrofit OkHttp client. This is the code I have so far:

```
private static Retrofit createMMSATService(String baseUrl, String user, String pass) {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    return retrofit;
}
```

I am using Retrofit 2.2 and [this tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit) suggests using `AuthenticationInterceptor`, but this class is not available.
Where is the correct place to add the credentials? Do I have to add them to my interceptor, client or Retrofit object? And how do I do that?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Find the Solution

1.Write a Interceptor class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.Credentials;
import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class BasicAuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private String credentials;

    public BasicAuthInterceptor(String user, String password) {
        this.credentials = Credentials.basic(user, password);
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Request authenticatedRequest = request.newBuilder()
            .header("Authorization", credentials).build();
        return chain.proceed(authenticatedRequest);
    }

}
```

2.Finally, add the interceptor to an OkHttp client

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(new BasicAuthInterceptor(username, password))
    .build();
```

Comment: Do you have a kotlin version of this interceptor that works? Been getting errors with the kotlin version i have. @Rajasekhar

Comment: @KBJ I implemented it like this: https://gist.github.com/seccomiro/85446c4849855615d1938133bce30738

Comment: Is it **addInterceptor** or **addNetworkInterceptor**?

Answer (score 9):

**Retrofit 2**

```
    public class ServiceGenerator {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "https://your.api-base.url";

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return createService(serviceClass, null, null);
    }

    public static <S> S createService(
            Class<S> serviceClass, String username, String password) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(username)
                && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            String authToken = Credentials.basic(username, password);
            return createService(serviceClass, authToken);
        }

        return createService(serviceClass, null);
    }

    public static <S> S createService(
            Class<S> serviceClass, final String authToken) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
            AuthenticationInterceptor interceptor =
                    new AuthenticationInterceptor(authToken);

            if (!httpClient.interceptors().contains(interceptor)) {
                httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);

                builder.client(httpClient.build());
                retrofit = builder.build();
            }
        }

        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

**Retrofit 1.9**

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "https://your.api-base.url";

    private static RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(API_BASE_URL)
                .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()));

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return createService(serviceClass, null, null);
    }

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String username, String password) {
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            // concatenate username and password with colon for authentication
            String credentials = username + ":" + password;
            // create Base64 encodet string
            final String basic =
                    "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

            builder.setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                    request.addHeader("Authorization", basic);
                    request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                }
            });
        }

        RestAdapter adapter = builder.build();
        return adapter.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

**AuthenticationInterceptor.java**

```
    public class AuthenticationInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private String authToken;

    public AuthenticationInterceptor(String token) {
        this.authToken = token;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();

        Request.Builder builder = original.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", authToken);

        Request request = builder.build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

### Usage

**Retrofit 2**

**Interface**

```
public interface LoginService {  
    @POST("/login")
    Call<User> basicLogin();
}
```

**Requester**

```
LoginService loginService =  
   ServiceGenerator.createService(LoginService.class, "user", "secretpassword");
Call<User> call = loginService.basicLogin();  
call.enqueue(new Callback<User >() {  
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            // user object available
        } else {
            // error response, no access to resource?
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
        // something went completely south (like no internet connection)
        Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Retrofit 1.9**

**Interface**

```
public interface LoginService {  
    @POST("/login")
    void basicLogin(Callback<User> cb);
}
```

**Requester**

```
LoginService loginService =  
    ServiceGenerator.createService(LoginService.class, "user", "secretpassword");
loginService.basicLogin(new Callback<User>() {  
    @Override
    public void success(User user, Response response) {
        // user object available
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        // handle errors, too
    }
});
```

[More information see here.](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit)

Comment: what fields are present in User model ?

Comment: I am using Retrofit 2, but getting type cast error at  httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor); it says:
Required type: Interceptor
Provided: AuthenticationInterceptor

Answer (score 3):

add header interceptor

```
public class HeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private PreferencesRepository mPrefs;
    private String mAuth;

    public HeaderInterceptor(PreferencesRepository p) {
        mPrefs = p;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        mAuth = (mPrefs.getAuthToken() != null)?mPrefs.getAuthToken():"";
        Request r = chain.request()
                .newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                // authorization token here
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + mAuth)
                .build();

        return chain.proceed(r);
    }
}
```

add cacheinterceptor (optional)

```
public class CacheInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    Context mContext;

    public CacheInterceptor(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

        Request request = chain.request();

        if (request.method().equals("GET")) {
            if (DeviceUtils.isConnected(mContext)) {
                request = request.newBuilder()
                        .header(Constant.CACHE_CONTROL, "only-if-cached")
                        .build();
            } else {
                request = request.newBuilder()
                        .header(Constant.CACHE_CONTROL, "public, max-stale=2419200")
                        .build();
            }
        }

        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(request);
        return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                .header(Constant.CACHE_CONTROL, "max-age=600")
                .build();
    }
}
```

implement it

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logger = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logger.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

long SIZE_OF_CACHE = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
Cache cache = new Cache(new File(mContext.getCacheDir(), "http"), SIZE_OF_CACHE);

new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(logger)
                    .addInterceptor(new HeaderInterceptor(u))
                    .cache(cache)
                    .addNetworkInterceptor(new CacheInterceptor(mContext))
                    .connectTimeout(Constant.CONNECTTIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(Constant.READTIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(Constant.WRITETIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course using auth interceptor is correct way (as explained in other answers). Although, if you need basic authentication only for single call, then auth header can be added directly in Retrofit request:

```
import okhttp3.Credentials

// Create credentials
val login = "some login"
val password = "some password"
// Below code will create correct Base64 encoded Basic Auth credentials
val credentials = Credentials.basic(login, password)

// Then in your Retrofit API interface
interface MyApi {
    @POST("get_user")
    fun getUser(@Header("Authorization") credentials: String): ResponseBody
}
```