# Translating a raw curl HTTP request into Retrofit format using Java

Tags: java, rest, curl, retrofit

I've made the following HTTP POST request via Postman for basic oauth authentication. When looking at the raw curl command that postman is making under the hood, it looks like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic Hdkdhfjdekrhfkhskierufh75947rhdklww==' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: c1b380a7-e4b3-4269-a789-1c7271f2986a' \
  -d grant_type=client_credentials
```

How do I send an equivalent request using Retrofit for Java? NOTE: I am writing a Java program in Eclipse -- I am not attempting this on Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an interceptor for doing the `basic authentication` stuff.

Refer: [Retrofit and OkHttp basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366164/retrofit-and-okhttp-basic-authentication)