# Why most people uses interceptor to add authentication header in retrofit?

Tags: android, authentication, retrofit2

- [Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366164/retrofit-and-okhttp-basic-authentication)
- [Medium Blog post](https://proandroiddev.com/configuring-retrofit-2-client-in-android-130455eaccbd)
- [More blog post](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit)

Every single one of them adds authentication in the interceptor stage instead of using `@Header` or `@Headers` annotation to Retrofit. Is there any reason why? Because sometimes you will have an API that requires no authentication (e.g. if you have a backend system status endpoint), and even though it won't break anything, it just feels unnecessary and also slightly hidden.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any reason why?

In many cases, it is more convenient than having to pass the authentication header as a parameter to each and every Retrofit method that needs the header.

For example, suppose that we are interfacing with a Web service that has 123,456,789 endpoints that we need to hit. With your plan, we need to:

- Add the `@Header`-annotated parameter to 123,456,789 methods on our Retrofit API interface
- Arrange to pass that parameter to all of our calls of these 123,456,789 methods

By using the interceptor, we add one interceptor, and it covers all of those methods.

> Because sometimes you will have an API that requires no authentication (e.g. if you have a backend system status endpoint)

Suppose that 789 of those endpoints do not need authentication. The remaining 123,456,000 do. With your plan, we need to:

- Add the `@Header`-annotated parameter to 123,456,000 methods on our Retrofit API interface
- Arrange to pass that parameter to all of our calls of these 123,456,000 methods

With the interceptor, we need one interceptor to handle all of it. That interceptor could have some whitelist to determine which endpoints can skip the header, using:

- Path regex
- Path segment match
- Full path match
- Whatever

---

Obviously, I am kidding somewhat here, in that few Web services have 123,456,789 endpoints.

However, there is some break-even point where having the interceptor will be simpler than handling the `@Header` parameter. Where that break-even point is depends on the development team.