# How to send a POST with basic auth using kotlin on an android app

Tags: android, http, kotlin, post, basic-authentication

Before anything, I'd like to mention that I'm fine using any library if it would help speed up or simplify the process.

I need to send a post request to an endpoint (`http://myserver.com/api/data/save`).
The body must be a json with this structure:

```json
{
   "id": "ABCDE1234",
   "date": "2021-05-05",
   "name": "Jason"
}
```

So, I need to make a post request. The endpoint requires authentication, so I need to incorporate the username and password. Where and how do I add them?

Best regards

Comment: If you're okay with using the library then retrofit might be a good choice. https://github.com/square/retrofit  And with retrofit you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43366296/9715339

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where and how do I add them?

There are multiple ways to add your authentication details to any API request. Assuming you are using [Retrofit 2](https://github.com/square/retrofit), one of the ideal ways to implement this is using [OkHttp Interceptors](https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/).

You need a class implementing `Interceptor`

```
class AuthInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var request = chain.request()

        // Add auth details here
        if (request.header("Authentication-required") != null) {
            request = request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("username", "username value")
                .addHeader("password", "password value")
                .build()
        }

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

In your API interface add a header to the respective API which requires authentication

```
@Headers("Authentication-required")
@POST("/save")
fun doSave(@Body data: PostData): Call<Status>
```

Finally, build your retrofit client with [OkHttpClient](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/) as

```
val authClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(AuthInterceptor())
    .build()

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(your_base_url)
    .client(authClient)
    .build()
```